# Espresso semi-parallel test execution fails on static objects?

Tags: android, junit4, android-testing, android-espresso

I am trying to use espresso and junit4. The problem seems to be that I have code that is statically initialized in activity.onCreate and deinitialized in activity.onDestroy

Now when I run espresso, the tests seem to run in "parallel". I added log class to activity onCreate and onDestroy.

What I am seeing is

```
onCreate = example.package.MainActivity@ABC
onCreate = example.package.MainActivity@JKL
onDestroy = example.package.MainActivity@ABC
onCreate = example.package.MainActivity@XYZ
onDestroy = example.package.MainActivity@JKL
onDestroy = example.package.MainActivity@XYZ
```

**and ofcourse it fails on NPE in third test because the second test's onDestroy ran after third's onCreate (which null-ed out the static code)**

Is this behaviour normal? Can I force espresso to teardown activity instance first and only then start a new one? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you use static resources and then release them on Destroy? This same error could come up in real application life cycle. You should not depend on when "onDestroy" is called

Comment: Why? When activity gets destroyed and onDestroy doesnt come, that means that process is being killed therefor everything gets released.. (Btw I oversimplified, we use native code etc, sadly it has to be this way for now)

Comment: Does MainActivity start another instance of MainActivity?  That's what it looks like to me.

Comment: No, you can observe the same logcat sequence even on a helloworld type project

Comment: And it does start new MainActivity and multiple of those share one static reference. Should keep these references on Activity instance and no problems would appear.

Comment: i know, but its legacy thing .. however i dont think the behaviour is right anyways